How to run multiple instances of Windows Sandbox at the same time?
When I try to run more than one instance of Windows Sandbox, then I get the following error:

Only one running instance of Windows Sandbox is allowed



Is there a way to overcome this limit? I want to run more than one instance of Windows Sandbox.

Based on this and your other question, perhaps you should be asking yourself whether Sandbox is the right solution for your needs. It sounds as though you actually need to be using a regular hypervisor, HyperV or VirtualBox or something like that.
Windows Sandbox is a more narrowly focused tool with specific purposes, while pretty much any other virtualization tool will be more flexible in its design and broader in its a capabilities.
From Microsoft's Windows Sandbox documentation, you can change these features of Sandbox:

A configuration file enables the user to control the following aspects
of Windows Sandbox:
vGPU (virtualized GPU): Enable or disable the virtualized GPU. If vGPU is disabled, the sandbox uses Windows Advanced Rasterization Platform (WARP).
Networking: Enable or disable network access within the sandbox.
Mapped folders: Share folders from the host with read or write permissions. Exposing host directories might allow malicious software to affect the system or steal data.
Logon command: A command that's executed when Windows Sandbox starts.
Audio input: Shares the host's microphone input into the sandbox.
Video input: Shares the host's webcam input into the sandbox.
Protected client: Places increased security settings on the Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) session to the sandbox.
Printer redirection: Shares printers from the host into the sandbox.
Clipboard redirection: Shares the host clipboard with the sandbox so that text and files can be pasted back and forth.
Memory in MB: The amount of memory, in megabytes, to assign to the sandbox.

